# Read a .csv file into an array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have stored a .csv file in this directory in Laravel 5 :

/storage/app/data.csv

Inside of this function I am trying to read the contents of this file and extract a few columns from it, like name and city to an array, sample code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function get_data() {

 $file_n = Storage::url('data.csv');
 $file = fopen($file_n, "r");
 $all_data = array();
 while ( ($data = fgetcsv($file, 200, ",")) !==FALSE {

     $name = $data[0];
     $city = $data[1];
     $all_data = $name. " ".$city;

     array_push($array, $all_data);
  }
  fclose($file);
}
```

I am getting an ErrorException in Controller:

```
fopen(/storage/data.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

But the file is there. Is there a better way to do this instead?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Try with `storage_path('data.csv')`.

Comment: `/storage/app/data.csv` != `/storage/data.csv`

Comment: If you need to use Storage class for this, specially if you are using s3 or minio, try `\Storage::disk('local_temp')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix($this->fileName);` to get the full file path. This is solution for Laravel 5.1, for Laravel 5.2 and up `::url()` function would work. for Laravel 5.7 and up `::path()` function would would work.

Answer (score 9):

I figured it out by using "storage_path".

```
...
$filename = storage_path('/app/data.csv');
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
$all_data = array();
while ( ($data = fgetcsv($file, 200, ",")) !==FALSE ) {
    ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;` to import Storage facade. Then `$storagePath = Storage::path($file);`

Answer (score 9):

Your issue is with the path as previous people pointed out.

You can use the helper function storage_path
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-storage-path

In your case it will be used like this:

```
storage_path('app/data.csv');
```

As a recomendation you can use this libary to work with CSV/Excel files, it's pretty easy to use: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Answer (score 7):

**Laravel 5.7**
try this :

```
Storage::disk('local')->path('import.csv');
```

It should  be good.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding a url key to my local disk config in config/filesystems.php like so:

```
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'url' => storage_path('app')
    ],
```

Now I can reference Storage::url('filename.txt') and it returns:

```
    /home/josh/apps/storage/app/filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
$file_n = Storage::get('data.csv');
```

Comment: This returns the csv file as a string.

Comment: This returns the csv file as a string. – 
You can avoid this by using
`$file_path = storage_path('file-name.csv');`
`$row = array_map("str_getcsv", file($file_path));`

Answer (score 0):

simply, one line can do it

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file(Storage::path('filename.csv')));
```