# How to get file from storage as a resource in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I would like to read a `.csv` file into an array in a `Laravel 5.8` environment. I can obtain the `.csv` file as a string using

```php
Storage::get('file.csv');
```

The string returned has no definitive delimiter. Rows appear to be separated by a space, but using a space as a delimiter in the PHP explode function returns an array with one item, containing the whole string.

I have tried `Storage::url()`, `storage_path()`, and the `asset()` helper.  All return the file as a string.  I would like to return the file as a resource, so I can apply the `fgetcsv` function, similar to the code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136331/read-a-csv-file-into-an-array-in-laravel).

The answers to this question seem to assume that the Storage facade returns the file as a resource. For me, the file is returned as a string.  The answers to this question do not make sense, except for the comment that the file is returned as a string - This returns the CSV file as a string.

How do I parse a `.csv` file into an array?

Comment: Where is the csv located relative to the laravel's root?

Comment: the file is located in storage/app .  Laravel can find the file without a problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution to the problem?