# Read CSV file stored in database and view in a html table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, html-table

I am developing a system in which can upload a CSV file and **view it in an HTML table**. After uploading CSV file saves in the database with an id, but I can't read that CSV file and view it in the HTML table. I want to read the CSV file into **an array and then view it in the table**. Please help me. It will be a great deal.

Controller files:-
**projectController**

```
<?PHP
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
 public function index($id)
{
    $project = Project::find($id);
    $data = array();
    // read the CSV and assign the data to $data
    return view('home')->with('project', $project)->with('data', $data);
   }
  }
```

**uploadFileController**

```
public function index()
 {
  return view('/');
 }
public function upload(Request $request)
 {
  $file = $request->file('csv');

  $project = new Project();

  $project->name = $request->name;

  $project->save();

  print_r($file);

  //Move Uploaded File
  $destinationPath = 'uploads';
  $file->move($destinationPath, $project->id . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension());

  return redirect("/project/{$project->id}");
}
```

This is how it looks:https://i.stack.imgur.com/yosHN.jpg

Comment: try this https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/basics.html

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139202/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a .csv file into an array in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136331/read-a-csv-file-into-an-array-in-laravel)

Comment: @Shibon Yes it does but how to enter this array into the HTML table.?